# Select a valid choice. [u'B', u'T'] is not one of the available choices

Tags: python, django

Getting this error in Django 1.7.

## Models.py

```
class Customize(models.Model):  
    CHECK_CHOICES = (
        ("B", "BHK"),
        ("T", "BTH"),
        ("L", "BKL"),
    )
    RAD_CHOICES = (
        (0, "TRUE"),
        (1, "FALSE")
    )

    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    hypervisior = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CHECK_CHOICES)
    enable_soe = models.BooleanField(choices=RAD_CHOICES,default=True)
    harden_file = models.FileField()
    param1 = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.profile
```

## Forms.py

```
class CustomizeProfileForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(CustomizeProfileForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.fields['hypervisior'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Customize.CHECK_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=False)
        self.fields['enable_soe'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices = Customize.RAD_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect)


    class Meta:
        model = Customize
        exclude = ('profile',)
```

## Views.py

```
def edit_profile(request, id):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customize_form = CustomizeProfileForm(request.POST,{'profile' : profile,'id': id})

        if customize_form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('display_profile'))
        else:
            print "Form is invalid"
    else:
        customize_form = CustomizeProfileForm()
    return render(request,'baas/edit_profile.html', {'form':customize_form,'profile' : profile, 'id': id} )
```

Comment: Can you please explain the error a little more?

Comment: While submitting django form I getting this error "Select a valid choice. [u'B', u'T'] is not one of the available choices.". I am using checkboxes  to get multiple values.

Comment: I deleted my earlier answer. It seems the error is happening only with multiple inputs, right? Does it work with a single input (say u'B')?

Comment: If you are sending multiple inputs, then it seems your 'hypervisor' field in the model does not support it. It is a charfield type, and can hold a single string.

Comment: I don't think (?) that you can use a boolean field with choice.  I think keep it boolean and use a radio button or change it to a character field to keep the dropdown.

Comment: No..even for single input it is throwing the same error.  "Select a valid choice. [u'B'] is not one of the available choices."